# Remove ns0, ns1, ns2 Namespaces From XML - Python

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml, elementtree

I am attempting to rewrite an XML with pre-determined namespaces using Python's lxml library, but I am encountering a bug when rewriting.  I am also attempting to modify an element value when I overwrite the xml, which seems to be working, but it then appends ns0, ns1, and ns2 namespaces in place of their pre-assigned prefixes.  Below is the code I am using, along with the input XML and the output I am getting.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree at ET
import os
import lxml
import glob

path = "C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\"  # contains the input XML

def tag_rename():

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xml")):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
        my_namespaces = dict([node for _, node in ET.iterparse(filename, events=['start-ns'])])
        ET.register_namespace=my_namespaces
        tree=ET.parse(filename)
        root=tree.getroot()
    
        for elem in root.findall('.//{http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0}nameIdentifier'):
            elem.tag = "{http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0}Test"

            with open(os.path.join(path, "test_rewrite.xml"), "wb") as b:
                tree.write(b)
tag_rename()
```

The input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="template.xsl"?>
<nas:Metadata xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0"
xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0">
 <gco:metadataIdentifier>
    <lan:textIdentifier>
          <cit:nameIdentifer>
         </cit:nameIdentifier>
   </lan:textIdentifier>
   </gco:metadataIdentifier>        
 </nas:Metadata>
```

The output XML:

```
<ns0:Metadata xmlns:ns3="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0"
xmlns:ns1="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
xmlns:ns2="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0">
 <ns1:metadataIdentifier>
    <ns2:textIdentifier>
          <ns3:Test>
         </ns3:Test>
   </ns2:textIdentifier>
   </ns1:metadataIdentifier>        
 </ns0:Metadata>
```

I have tried multiple approaches using lxml and eTree to preserve the original prefixes for the namespaces but still cannot figure out how to fix this, any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want the output to be `cit:`, `gco:` and `lan:`.

Comment: tdelaney - Correct, I want to preserve the cit:, gco:, and lan: namespaces upon rewrite of the XML.  I am running the script within the Spyder environment and it seemed to have worked one time, but without changing anything and re-running I am now continuously getting the ns0, ns1, ns2 errors.  It's quite frustrating, but any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: The indentation is not quite right, The `for` should be in the `def` and that second `with` to write should be dedented I think. And a bit of a nit pick. Write tests easy to run. I had to rewrite the code to not scan a directory and open a file called test.py. Try to make a script as close to runnable as possible.

Comment: tdelaney - You are correct, I actually didn't catch the indentation error in my copy/paste of the script but the for/with statements are under the def within my Spyder environment.  But what are the main rewrites for the code to not scan the directory?  I really appreciate your help/insights!  :)

Comment: nit pick2 - the xml isn't quite right either. `nas:` isn't defined. cit:nameIdentifer is misspelled.

Comment: Try these instead -  <nas:MD_Metadata>, <cit:role>, <gco:characterString>, and <lan:language> for the opening tags in the input.xml.  This should correctly point to the namespaces that reference the URLs.  In fact, it might be more feasible to remove the <nas:MD_Metadata> opening and closing tags for troubleshooting purposes (it's been problematic for me from the start).  I'm just trying to test out proof of concept for a project, thanks again!

Comment: ElementTree is a nightmare for namespaces, IMHO. Just change the import to `import lxml.etree as ET` and you are almost there. Add `xml_declaration=True` to the write and that should be  it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to make a few changes to your xml example, including inventing a `<root>` tag holding a fake `nas` namespace declaration. I also trimmed the script a bit to handle a single file. After that, it was just a case of switching to `lxml` which has better namespace support than `ElementTree` and adding a parameter to the write.

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="template.xsl"?>
<root xmlns:nas="http://this/is/not/right">
<nas:Metadata xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0"
xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0">
 <gco:metadataIdentifier>
    <lan:textIdentifier>
          <cit:nameIdentifier>
         </cit:nameIdentifier>
   </lan:textIdentifier>
   </gco:metadataIdentifier>        
 </nas:Metadata>
 </root>
```

test.py

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import os
import lxml
import glob

def tag_rename(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
        my_namespaces = dict([node 
            for _, node in ET.iterparse(filename, events=['start-ns'])])
        for item in my_namespaces.items():
            print(item)
        ET.register_namespace=my_namespaces
        tree=ET.parse(filename)
        root=tree.getroot()
    
        for elem in root.findall('.//{http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0}nameIdentifier'):
            elem.tag = "{http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0}Test"
        with open("output.xml", "wb") as b:
            tree.write(b,xml_declaration=True)

tag_rename("test.xml")
```

output.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="template.xsl"?><root xmlns:nas="http://this/is/not/right">
<nas:Metadata xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0" xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0" xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0">
 <gco:metadataIdentifier>
    <lan:textIdentifier>
          <cit:Test>
         </cit:Test>
   </lan:textIdentifier>
   </gco:metadataIdentifier>        
 </nas:Metadata>
```

Comment: AWESOME!!  That did the trick, and yeah I've had my own "fun" with ElementTree so lxml seems a bit more functional.  Your edits work great and will save me headaches, I'll happily acknowledge your solution as the correct answer - Thanks again!

Comment: ElementTree came around before there was a good standard way to handle xml. `lxml` depends on libxml2 and libxslt which were historically difficult to get cross platform. That's been pretty much fixed so for me, ElementTree is no longer needed. Goodbye and thanks for the fish. There are also direct bindings into libxml2 and libxslt which are perhaps a bit of a dark art but for bulk processing of xml documents may be faster.